# Can't Drop Table Cross Database in Procedure Netezza

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, netezza

i newbie in netezza (Running version netezza Release 7.1.0.1-P1 [Build 37788]), i have 2 Database :

1. DB "A"
2. DB "B"

in DB "A" i have Procedure SP_DROP_TMP_TABLE_DBB()

```
create or replace procedure SP_DROP_TMP_TABLE_DBB()
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL RETURNS INT4 AS
BEGIN_PROC

DECLARE

BEGIN   

    /* HAPUS TABLE HASIL CLUSTERING */
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
        DROP TABLE DBB.USR3.STG_AP_LOC_KMEANS_OUT;
    ';

    /* HAPUS ALL_NMS_DETAIL */
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
        DROP TABLE DBB.USR3.ALL_DETAIL;
    ';

END;

END_PROC;
```

SP_DROP_TMP_TABLE_DBB() is for delete all TMP Table in DB"B", but i need call this from DB"A"(SP created in DB DB"A")

but when i call in DB"A"

```
CALL SP_DROP_TMP_TABLE_DBB()
```

the result is :

```
ERROR:  Cross Database Access not supported for this type of command
```

whereas, when i run in manual Query at DB"A" :

```
DROP TABLE DBB.USR3.STG_AP_LOC_KMEANS_OUT;
```

it's working

i don't understand why it's happen, maybe you have suggest to help me

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations that write to the database or database catalog for *DBB* cannot be executed from *DBA*, and this includes DROP TABLE.

When you run this command and it succeeds:

```
DROP TABLE DBB.USR3.STG_AP_LOC_KMEANS_OUT;
```

then I have to believe that you must not be attached to *DBA*.

Are you running your test commands from Aginity, NZSQL, or another tool?

Here is how the system should behave.

```
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzsql -d dba
Welcome to nzsql, the IBM Netezza SQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help on internal slash commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> drop table dbb.admin.STG_AP_LOC_KMEANS_OUT;
ERROR:  Cross Database Access not supported for this type of command
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \c dbb
You are now connected to database dbb.
DBB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> drop table dbb.admin.STG_AP_LOC_KMEANS_OUT;
DROP TABLE
```

On other thing to note with regard to stored procedures is that you can define a stored procedure in DBA that writes/drops in DBB, but that SP in DBA will have to be called while connected to DBB.

For example:

```
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create or replace procedure SP_DROP_TMP_TABLE_DBB()
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> LANGUAGE NZPLSQL RETURNS INT4 AS
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> BEGIN_PROC
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$> DECLARE
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$> BEGIN
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>     /* HAPUS TABLE HASIL CLUSTERING */
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>         DROP TABLE DBB.ADMIN.STG_AP_LOC_KMEANS_OUT;
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>     ';
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>     /* HAPUS ALL_NMS_DETAIL */
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>         DROP TABLE DBB.ADMIN.ALL_DETAIL;
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>     ';
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$> END;
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$>
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)$> END_PROC;
CREATE PROCEDURE
DBA.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \c dbb
You are now connected to database dbb.
DBB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> call dba.admin.SP_DROP_TMP_TABLE_DBB();
 SP_DROP_TMP_TABLE_DBB
-----------------------

(1 row)
```

Here are some sample screenshots of how it should/shouldn't work in Aginity.

Here is an image of the expected cross-database access error.

[image]

And here is an image of the successful run connected to the appropriate database.

[image]

Comment: Ok. Sometimes it can be easy to get mixed up as to which database you are connected to in Aginity.  a DROP of a table in DBB should not be possible if you are connected to DBA. You can verify which database you are connected to in the DB dropdown list above the SQL query windows in Aginity.

Comment: Wow.. Sp i can't drop table in DB"B" using SP from DB"A" right? Why it hapen? Thx

Comment: You can use SP from DBA to drop a table in DBB, but you have to call the SP from DBA while you are connected to DBB (that's the example above).  The reason is that in Netezza there is a general limitation that you cannot update a database that you are not connected to directly.

Comment: But,  why work if not use SP, i mean just run query in aginity.. Like example in my question...

Comment: Can you post a full screenshot of it working in Aginity? It should not work in Aginity.

Comment: yeah...it's can't work...but tomorrow i can run,,i'm confused with netezza ==',,but thx for your help :)